# How to amend the mentioned sentence so that it contains less repetition?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

> The difference between A and B adds up to the former being beneficial
>   while the latter failing to be beneficial.

I don't like the way "being beneficial" is repeated in the sentence. The following seems to me not a good alternative as it is vague. Is it? Any better suggestion?

> The difference between A and B adds up to the former being while the
>   latter failing to be beneficial.

Comment: "The difference between A and B is that A is beneficial and/while B is not."

Answer (score 1):

In a case such as this, the last "beneficial" can be implicit; if you write "The difference between A and B adds up to the former being beneficial while the latter failing to be.", the word "beneficial" will be understood at the end. You can also say "The difference between A and B adds up to the former being beneficial while the latter not." or "The difference between A and B is that the former is beneficial while the latter is not".